# 【FileNotFoundError】when opening executable of streamlit project (selenium included) made by cxfreeze

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt, streamlit, file-not-found

#### Project info

I created a little project with **[streamlit](/questions/tagged/streamlit)** app framework (*main.py*), also included some other packages (**[selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium)**, **[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)**, **[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)**).

#### Wrapper script info

In order to share it with my colleagues, I followed the instruction on the internet and created another wrapper script (*run_streamlit.py*) that will be used to call my *main.py* (all the packages imported in the *main.py* were imported in *run_streamlit.py*) utilizing **[subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess)**.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run('streamlit run main.py')
```

#### Command promt info

For the sake of convenience, I use **[command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt)** to run the following command to create the executable file (in the default *exe.win-amd63-3.8* folder)

```
cxfreeze -c run_streamlit.py
```

#### Error occured in others computer

I then make a copy of my *main.py* in to the *exe.win-amd63-3.8* folder after it was created, it worked well in my own computer, but **[FileNotFoundError]** occured when my colleague tried to open it.

[Error occured in other's computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKcW4.jpg)

I'm thinking it's the absolute and relative address of all the packages that cause the problem.
Is there any precise explanation why this problem occur ?
What's the most convenient way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Typo: you're trying to run a command named `s` with the arguments `'t'`, `'r'`, `'e'`, `'a'`, .... Try `["streamlit", "run", "main.py"]`, or pass `shell=True` if you want to spawn a shell interpreter to intrepret and run an arbitrary shell command instead of spawning a process directly

Comment: Do note that the behavior of `subprocess.run` with a string argument is platform dependent. You should stick to the sequence argument unless you know what you're doing - the subprocess docs recommend as much: _"If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent ... it is recommended to pass args as a sequence"_

Comment: I think I've tried both options but the error still occured
(but I'll try again to make sure whether it's my problem though)
Thank you for the comment! @Brian61354270

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)